# How to compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_{0}^{x} f(t)t \space dt $?

Tags: limits, derivatives, definite-integrals, continuity

For a continuous function $f: R \to R $ Define:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_{0}^{x} f(t)t \space dt $$
Since the function is continuous I can assume that it's also integrable since continuity implies integrability. I assume furthermore that there exists a function $F$ which is an antiderivative of $f$ for which the following are true:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx =F(b)-F(a) \space\space\space\space\space a,b\in R \space  $$
$$ \lim_{x \to x_{0}} \frac{F(x)-F(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=f(x)$$
And that for $f$
$$ \lim_{x \to x_{0}} f(x)=f(x_{0})$$

In order to find the limit, I used partial integration and ended up with:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)(x-1) +F(0)}{x^2}$$
At this point, I tried to use L'Hôpital's rule and ended up with the value $\frac{f(0)}{2}$ which seems totally wrong to me .
Any advice would be appreciated, I mainly think that my solution idea is wrong, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By L'Hôpital's rule, this limit is equal to
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{xf(x)}{2x} = \frac12\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \frac{f(0)}2.$$
(Use the first Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate the integral, since the integrand is guaranteed continuous.) You were correct.

Comment: Even though I've found the correct answer, I still feel that I've taken a shortcut or a path that's not permitted. Is the limit (which I've stated) after I used partial integration correct or should I have handled the integration in another way in order to reach $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\,f(x)}{2x} $ ?

Comment: You don't need to integrate. Use the part of the FTC that tells you how to differentiate $\int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ when $g$ is continuous. I don't follow your solution. If you're going to use integration by parts, you'll need to integrate $\int_0^x F(t)\,dt$, won't you?

Comment: Ok, now I see, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The limit is indeed $f(0)/2$. 
L'Hôpital's Rule applies because the limit of the quotient of the derivatives of numerator and denominator exists. Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}\int_0^x f(t)\,t\,dt
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\,f(x)}{2x}=\frac{f(0)}2
$$

Comment: But if you use the antiderivative you get:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_{0}^{x} f(t)t \space dt = 
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} (F(x)-F(0)) =\\
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac 1 x \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x} =\bigg(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac 1 x\bigg)\bigg( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}\bigg) =\\
\pm \infty \cdot f(x)$$

Comment: @Sudix You get $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x^2}$. You can only separate the limit as you did when the limit of the factors exist and some extra cases, but not in the case that one for the factors tends to $\infty$ and the other to $0=f(0)\cdot 0$ (not $f(x )$ as you wrote) as happens here.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft You're right, I forgot about the case $f(0)=0$, but if $f(0) \not = 0$, we can do this seperation, so something still is off

Comment: @Sudix The factor $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}$ is $(f(x)\cdot x)|_{x=0}$, if $f(0)\neq0$ the factor is still zero.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Let's take $f(x) = 2x+1$, then $\int_0^x f(x)\space dx = x^2+x$, and therefore $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1 {x^2} \int_0^x f(x)\space dx = \pm \infty$

Comment: @Sudix Inside the integral is $f(t)t$, not $f(t)$.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Oh..., overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*An approach not relying on L'Hopital's Rule.*

We have, for $x\neq 0$ and with the change of variable $u=\frac{t}{x}$, $$
\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x t f(t)dt
= \int_0^1 u f(xu) du
$$
Now, it is not hard to prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^1 u f(xu) du
= \int_0^1 u \lim_{x\to 0} f(xu) du
= \int_0^1 u f(0) du
= f(0)\left [\frac{x^2}{2}\right]^1_0
= \frac{f(0)}{2}
$$
(where the swapping limit/integral can be justified e.g. by arguing about uniform convergence, using continuity of $f$).

Comment: Nice approach. You don't even need to think about things like uniform convergence if you instead consider $\left|\int_0^1 uf(xu)\,du - \int_0^1 uf(0)\,du\right|\le \int_0^1 u|f(xu)-f(0)|du< \epsilon\int_0^1 u\,du$ whenever $x<\delta$ by continuity (since $xu\le x$ for all $0\le u\le 1$).

Comment: @TedShifrin: I used the same approach as you mention in your comment and I saw your comment later.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, good point.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(t) $ as $f(t) - f(0)+f(0)$ and then the desired limit is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}\{f(t)-f(0)\}t\,dt+\frac{f(0)}{2}\tag{1}$$ Next we can show that the first limit above is $0$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Then by continuity we have a $\delta>0$ such that $$|f(x) - f(0)|<\epsilon $$ whenever $|x|<\delta$. Thus we have $$\left|\int_{0}^{x}\{f(t)-f(0)\}t\,dt\right |\leq\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)-f(0)|t\,dt<\frac{\epsilon x^2}{2}$$ whenever $0<x<\delta$. Similar inequality holds when $-\delta <x<0$. It thus follows that the first limit in $(1)$ above is $0$. Thus the desired limit is $f(0)/2$.